# OnClick event doesn't work for TreeView in React JS if it passed as props from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, treeview

I have two components:

```
1- TrackerStudent.js
2- TreeViewTracker.js
```

### I used props to provide an event onClick to TreeViewTracker component :

```
  function TrackerStudent() {
   
  function handleItemClick(e) {
     
    console.log("Item Clicked >> " + e);
  }

  return (
    <>        
        <TreeViewTracker   onClick={handleItemClick} />        
    </>
  );
  }
}

export default TrackerStudent;
```

in TreeViewTracker.js Component , I wrote:

```
function TreeViewTracker(props) {

 <TreeView >
      ....  
    <TreeItem  onClick={props.handleItemClick} />
      ....
 </TreeView>
..
export default TreeViewTracker;
```

---

But the onClick event wasn't triggered.

I tried

```
`onClick={handleItemClick}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `handleItemClick` function as a prop called `onClick` to the `TreeViewTracker` component:

```
// TrackerStudent component
<TreeViewTracker onClick={handleItemClick} />
```